# Downgrade 10.7.2 to 10.7.1?

Tags: macos, ssl

Is it possible to downgrade from Mac OS X 10.7.2 to 10.7.1 without deleting all files?

I want to do this because of this: https://superuser.com/questions/349740/mac-os-x-lion-10-7-2-update-breaks-ssl

Comment: Yep. Reboot into Lion's Recovery HD and reinstall Lion (10.7.0). Then download the 10.7.1 update from Apple. Reinstalling Lion won't erase any of your files or installed apps. It's quite painless actually. It also doesn't leave behind anything from the old installation (10.7.2).

Comment: @cksum The Recovery HD actually just installs 10.7.2 again, not 10.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - but you can make a back up, erase and only install 10.7.1 and migrate the user and apps back from the backup.

If you run into oddball crashes - you can chase them down if the solution isn't obvious. You can then always go to 10.7.2 or worst case erase and go back to 10.7.2 and re-do the migration a second time from the snapshot you have now.

It's not generally good to go back, but sometimes you don't have the things that really matter or the side effects are manageable or you can re-set up those things by hand once you have discovered them.

Spotlight also makes it very easy to see what has been changed since you went to 10.7.2 and you could just revert to then and move those by hand.

Nothing about this is automatic, but it's certainly doable.

Comment: How do I only install 10.7/10.7.1 from the Recovery HD? It directly installs 10.7.2.

Comment: I don't know for certain, but 10.7.2 also came with a Recover HD update and perhaps that is forcing the issue. Assuming you have the installer for 10.7 (in USB key or from Apple as USB or download) you could erase the mac and start over and be sure to not apply the Recovery HD update.